# ShellExecuteEx shifting focus to previously opened application for short time returning back to .exe again

Tags: visual-c++, shellexecute, shellexecuteex

I am using `ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo)` for launching an `.exe` , when `.exe` get launched from my application then the windows focus shifts towards the previously opened application (like windows explore) for very short time around 1 sec and after that it returns to `.exe`. I want my focus should be on exe without going to any to any application for short time.

Code for reference:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = mainWndHWnd;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open";
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"abc.exe";
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = buffer;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNA;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
```

Comment: I tried with ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;  but doesn't solve my problem

Comment: It depends on your abc.exe. Check if it exits quickly. This might be the case that it exits immediately and then Windows bring focus on previous window.

Comment: my exe is a c# form application , it remain for long time . Also focus goes for short time to previously opened application and come back to exe immediately . Focus comes to parent application when i close the exe since it is modal on parent application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you call

```
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
```

from one of your application and immediately exit it. Is that right?

In that case, the process you are creating may not be started/initialized yet, and Windows **HAS** to set focus to some window, so it goes to the previously focused one.

You may want to wait in your first application for the second one to get started, for example, with WaitForInputIdle() function.

Comment: hi, abc.exe doesn't exit immediately, it wait for some input from user and process it and after that it is exit . focus is coming to exe but after some short time (by going back to previous application )

Comment: I was asking about the application that calls `ShellExecuteEx()`, NOT the `abc.exe` that is created. Does that *FIRST* application exits immediately after calling `ShellExecuteEx()`? And who is that `parent application`? Could you call them A, B and C and explain the scenario again?